# For what values of $\alpha$ is the improper integral exist?

Tags: calculus

For which $\alpha > 0$ does the improper integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2\cos x}{(1+x^2)^{\frac\alpha2}}\ dx$$

exists?
[image: workings]
[image: my workings]

Comment: Remember to put dollar signs around your MathJax. Enclose with \$ ' \$ at the start and end for regular text, or \$\$ ' \$\$ for enlarged text.

Comment: @Huffman_Coding I have attached a photo of my attempt at some workings so far.

Comment: The image is dark and a bit difficult to read.

Comment: Just added a scanned version on it @A---B hope its better

Comment: unreadable text please type it

Comment: @AmberTidd Yes it is readable. But some people here get a tad bit emotional when they don't see MathJax used in posts. Please try to use it, reference link : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.